# My touchpad, keyboard, and any other input devices intermittenly stopped working on Asus Zenbook UX303LB

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

Here is my story:
I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in my zenbook ux303lb. The first time, my touchpad is working, but gesture wasn't at all. For example, my touchpad can't recognize two scroll fingers gesture and the it didn't have option to enable it in "Mouse Settings".

Long story short, I managed to enabled it by following this guide: [focaltech dkms](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/focaltech-dkms), with the trade off, I had to pull the kernel 3.19.0-26-generic version. It was 3.16.xx version at first time I installed the OS.

After that, I observe that every time I use the touchpad, keyboard and any other input stopped working intermittently. Somehow it started working after pressing CTRL+ALT+F2 and then CTRL+ALT+F7. Another observation is, this bug is not happening when I only use external mouse.

Is there any way in how to fix it?

Additional Info:
- I use NVidia Driver version 346.82

Comment: You may be having problems with your nvidia drivers

Comment: @BMicraft: so what you are suggesting is to update my nvidia driver? Or is it because incompatibility problem with the kernel version?

Comment: I don't know which versions are faulty but try disabling the nvidia card int the `nvidia-settings`(you may have to install them) and see if it continuous to happen to be sure that is is the problem.

Comment: Continuing as "Answer" so you can accept it in case the driver is the problem,

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest `nvidia-355` driver(ppa:xorg-edgers), it does not have the issue of freezing for me.

You can install the ppa by using this command:

```
apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
apt-get update
```

Install the driver using ubuntus driver manager (or how it's called)

Comment: Hi, it still doesn't work :(, the issues are still persist

Comment: Yeah, noticed that aswell, although it does not happen that often. Try to not use the touchpad but a mouse instead. This solved it for me. I know it is the nvidia card though, because if I switch to Intel HD Graphics 4000 this never happens.